# Explain this newton's method problem with critical values as your initial guess?

Tags: calculus

Suppose Newton's Method is used with an
initial guess Xo that lies at a critical point
(a, b), where b does not equal 0. What happens to X1 and later
approximations? Give reasons for your
answer.

Comment: Just look at the formula that gives $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $x_n$. If the Newton Method has been explained geometrically, look also at the geometry.

Comment: But Xsub1 and later approximations (X2,X3,etc) cannot be found when Xsub0 lies at a critical point correct? @AndréNicolas

Comment: That's exactly the point.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Different people have different definitions of *critical point*. But all points where the derivative is $0$ are considered to be critical points. Sometimes points where the derivative does not exist are considered to be critical points.

Now look at the formula that gives $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $x_n$, and let $n=0$. If $(x_0, f(x_0))=(a,b)$ is a critical point, do you see the problem?

If the Newton Method has been explained geometrically, ub terms of where a tangent line crosses the $x$-axis, you may want to explain the issue geometrically.

Comment: right, and since newtons method is a sequence of approximation, it would be impossible to approximate X2,X3, and so on without the initial output for X1 correct? Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Of course we can always say oops. let's start with another $x_0$.